# Why is Dafny allowing uninitialized return result?

Tags: dafny

In this method:

```
datatype Results = Foo | Bar

method test() returns (r:Result)
{
}
```

Dafny verifies OK and test() returns Foo. Which is technically correct (it does return a value of the correct type) however I was expecting Dafny to complain that the result has not been set by the method itself. What test() is doing is similar to doing:

```
return;
```

in a C function that is supposed to return an int.

Is there a way to make Dafny verify that a methods results are always set before the method returns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flag you want is `/definiteAssignment:2`:

```
  /definiteAssignment:<n>
      0 - ignores definite-assignment rules; this mode is for testing only--it is
          not sound
      1 (default) - enforces definite-assignment rules for compiled variables and fields
          whose types do not support auto-initialization and for ghost variables
          and fields whose type is possibly empty
      2 - enforces definite-assignment for all non-yield-parameter
          variables and fields, regardless of their types
      3 - like 2, but also performs checks in the compiler that no nondeterministic
          statements are used; thus, a program that passes at this level 3 is one
          that the language guarantees that values seen during execution will be
          the same in every run of the program
```

This is what Dafny says on your code says with that flag:

> test.dfy(5,0): Error: out-parameter 'r', which is subject to definite-assignment rules, might be uninitialized at this return point